# Compare dates, monthly period + 1 day

Tags: php, date, date-math

I need to compare current date against a starting date, idea being that on every month + 1 day it will return as if only one month has gone by. So if starting date is **2014-10-27**, on **2014-11-27** it will still show Less than a month ago, and on **2014-11-28** it'll show more than a month ago.

Currently I have:

```
     $start_datetime = '2014-10-27';
    // true if my_date is more than a month ago

    if (strtotime($start_datetime) < strtotime('1 month ago')){
    echo ("More than a month ago...");
    } else {
    echo ("Less than a month ago...");
    }
```

Comment: How could you modify a date to represent that same date one month ago?

Answer (score 5):

DateTime is best suited for date math in PHP. DateTime objects are comparable which makes this very readable, too.

```
$start_datetime = new DateTimeImmutable('2014-10-27');
$one_month_ago  = $start_datetime->modify('- 1 month');

if ($start_datetime < $one_month_ago){
    echo ("More than a month ago...");
} else {
    echo ("Less than a month ago...");
}
```

For PHP versions older than 5.5 you need to clone `$startDate` for this to work:

```
$start_datetime = new DateTime('2014-10-27');
$one_month_ago  = clone $start_datetime;
$one_month_ago  = $one_month_ago->modify('- 1 month');

if ($start_datetime < $one_month_ago){
    echo ("More than a month ago...");
} else {
    echo ("Less than a month ago...");
}
```

Comment: @vascowhite I've been anticipating it, too. Fortunately making this work with PHP versions older than 5.5 just requires one more line of code.

Comment: Also see the date echo'd in the link :) I do like immutable objects though.

Comment: And I am in older version, can you please ellaborate @JohnConde

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it still doesn't works, I got:
stack trace: #0 E:\www\root\compare\comp2.php(5): DateTime->__construct('2014-10-27') #1 {main} thrown in E:\www\root\compare\comp2.php on line 5.

line 5 = $start_datetime = new DateTime('2014-10-27');

Comment: @JohnConde I believe you ;)